# Blender And UE4 - Noob : Using Model W/ Animations

Tags: animation, blender, unreal-engine4, skeletal-animation

I'm very sorry, but I tried looking everywhere and I cant fins an answer. I made a model in blender, and exported it as an .fbx file, imported it into UE4 third person default project. I tried  with and without a custom project. I need help getting my mesh into the blueprint animation. [image]

In short, how do I get the character I made in blender to replace the character blueprint that comes default.

Comment: Unity has there own [answers](http://answers.unity3d.com) site, I also expect you would get more unity help at [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) than here.

Comment: UE4 != Unity sambler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you would create your own blueprint object or character model (programming model) which references the fbx file and the animations required.

There are tutorials on doing this as it is quite involved, I suggest Udemy or one of the other groups for online training.